# Is a non-Newtonian gas possible?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, home-experiment, viscosity

I was wondering if it was possible to have a Non-Newtonian Gas. I was planning a science fair experiment to try to create one if its possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They exist, but are rare and as far as I know they always contain 'exotic' molecules that will probably be unsuitable for a science fair. A quick google results in this paper as the major result: [Cousins et al. 1997 PRL, 79 (2285)](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.2285)

Cousins et al. study the excitation gas in superfluid  $^3$He-*B* and find that it behaves in a non-newtonian fashion.

Comment: I don't *think* this is even a gas as the OP means it - it is a "gas" of excitations, similar to a "gas" of phonons, but it is in liquid(-ish) helium.

Comment: @ChrisWhite That's a good point indeed, but since this was the first thing to pop up in a search I figured it would at least be helpful to mention it